# Force use of the default content of a master page asp:ContentPlaceholder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page, content, custom-masterpage

I have a ContentPlaceholder in my custom master that has default content.  I want to always use this default content.  However there are some pages in the 14 hive that have an asp:Content that superceeds the default content.  Is there a way to prevent this and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to prevent the ContentPlaceHolder from being 'overriden'.  If you have control over the html of the masterpage, you could can:

- Move the defaults contents outside the content placeholder (if you are sure that the content should always be present on the page). Then put a `<div style="display:none">..</div>` around the placeholder.
- Do the above but put the default contents into a new placeholder with a new unique name.
- Alter the application pages / page layouts that are implementing the placeholder.
- Do something clever through the object model.

Comment: Head slap....many thanks...hate when i miss the obvious :)